# firefox bug - Options disappeared on hover

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drop-down-menu

Firefox represents a bug when I insert a select box on mouseenter event. The whole dropdown list is gone on hover. How can I fix this bug?

```js
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
    this.innerHTML = '<select><option value=1>2</option><option value=2>3</option></select>';
});
```

```css
#test{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach where we can append to the `<div>` element. In this example, `mouseenter` may fire a lot, so I wrapped this code in a closure to execute once to demo appending once. You can surely craft this to your needs but this approach should allow a bit more functionality than overwriting the html of the element

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xpubt12g/)

```
var append = (function(ele, node) { // execute once closure
    var executed = false;
    return function (ele, node) {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            ele.appendChild(node);
        }
    };
})();

document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    var that = this;
    var node = document.createElement('select');
    node.innerHTML = '<option value=1>2</option><option value=2>3</option>'
    append(that, node);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't select a value in Chrome either so this wouldn't be just a Firefox bug I think.

Anyway here is a fix. Just load the select when it's not loaded on mouse enter.

```
 document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
  if(this.innerHTML===""){  
    this.innerHTML = '<select><option value=1>2</option><option value=2>3</option></select>';}
    });
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use the 'mouseover' event, I tried your code with 'mouseenter' in Safari and it doesn't work. It doesn't load the selection at all, while 'mouseover' works in FF,Chrome,Safari.